# QT QML - access qml model from another class

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I need to have "myclient" class that handles input data from socket. After data arrives it should call function "add" from qml model class "mymodel". How can I access the instance of the model that is created in main.cpp?

Here is an example which has text entering functions:

Classes: main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "mymodel.h"
#include "myclient.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    MyModel *theModel=new MyModel;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("theModel", theModel);

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    myclient cli;    //doesn't add the data to list in it's constructor
    theModel.add("Added in main.cpp");   //works as expected

    return app.exec();
}
```

Now here is class myModel.h

```
#ifndef MYMODEL_H
#define MYMODEL_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QHash>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>


class MyModel: public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyModel(QObject* parent=nullptr): QAbstractListModel (parent)
    {
        innerModel.append("Bob");
        innerModel.append("Patrick");
        innerModel.append("Alice");
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        if (parent.isValid())
            return 0;
        return innerModel.size();
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        if (parent.isValid())
            return 0;
        return 2;
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role=Qt::DisplayRole) const override
    {
        qDebug() << index << role;
        switch (role)
        {
            case Qt::DisplayRole:
            case Qt::UserRole + 1:
                return innerModel.at(index.row());
            case Qt::UserRole + 2:
                return QString::number(index.row() + 1);
        }
        return QVariant();
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE QHash<int,QByteArray> roleNames() const override
    {
        QHash<int,QByteArray> roles;
        roles.insert(Qt::UserRole + 1, "name");
        roles.insert(Qt::UserRole + 2, "index");
        return roles;
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE void add(QString const& name)
    {
        beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
        innerModel.append(name);
        endInsertRows();
    }
    private:
        QList<QString> innerModel;
};
#endif // MYMODEL_H
```

and finally myclient.h

I tried this way but i'm aware that i'm creating another instance of myModel here

```
#ifndef MYCLIENT_H
#define MYCLIENT_H
#include "mymodel.h"

class myclient
{
public:
    myclient()
    {
        MyModel mod;
        mod.add("Added from myclient");
    }
};

#endif // MYCLIENT_H
```

How can I access methods of myModel (instance that is loaded into engine in main.cpp) in other parts of the app? Or is there another way of doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the model in the client class then pass it as the argument of the constructor to be a member of the class.

**myclient.h**

```cpp
#ifndef MYCLIENT_H
#define MYCLIENT_H
#include "mymodel.h"

class myclient
{
public:
    myclient(MyModel *model): m_model(model)
    {
        m_model->add("Added from myclient");
    }
private:
    MyModel *m_model;
};

#endif // MYCLIENT_H
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
// ...
myclient cli(&theModel);
// ...
```